# Flutter google places autocomplete not working as of fall 2021

Tags: ios, flutter, google-maps, flutter-dependencies, google-places-autocomplete

When using the api in a flutter mobile application, I cannot see suggested places underneath the search. I used to be able to. As of last fall I cannot. All I see is a loading sign for .1 seconds. I contacted google and they said my api key was working.

Any help either fixing the problem or helping me figure out how to debug it would be greatly appreciated!!

In my pubspec.yaml, you can see all the packages I have installed:

```
name: coolertalk
description: A new Flutter project.
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  fl_chart: ^0.36.2
  
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.6
  uuid: ^2.0.0
  image: ^2.1.19
  animator: 0.1.4
  path_provider: ^1.6.5
  timeago: 2.0.17
  cached_network_image: ^2.4.1
  flutter_svg: 
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.8.1
  dropdown_formfield: ^0.1.2
  share: ^0.6.4+3
  pdf: ^1.8.1
  flutter_full_pdf_viewer: ^1.0.6
  share_extend: "^1.1.7"
  dio: ^3.0.9
  csv: ^4.0.3
  url_launcher: ^5.4.11
  flutter_image_compress: ^0.7.0
  exif: ^1.0.3
  lite_rolling_switch: ^0.1.1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.4
  firebase_storage: 
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
  intl: ^0.16.1
  advance_pdf_viewer: ^1.1.6
  firebase_core: 
  photo_view: ^0.10.3
  flutter_signin_button: 
  email_validator: '^1.0.0'
  sign_in_with_apple: ^2.5.4
  flutter_markdown: ^0.5.2
  apple_sign_in: ^0.1.0
  provider: ^4.3.2+2
  flutter_secure_storage: ^3.3.5
  rflutter_alert: ^1.0.3
  purchases_flutter: ^1.1.1
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2
  google_fonts: 
  flutter_countdown_timer: ^4.1.0
  image_cropper: ^1.4.1
  image_picker:
  firebase_performance: ^0.4.3
  english_words: ^4.0.0
  sliding_up_panel: ^2.0.0+1
  flutter_google_places:
  google_maps_webservice: 
  geocoding:
  geolocator: 
  # firebase_crashlytics: ^0.2.4
  # flutter_google_places: ^0.2.8
  # google_maps_webservice: ^0.0.19
  # geocoding: ^1.0.5
  # geolocator: ^6.2.1
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
    
# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  fonts:
    - family: Signatra
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Signatra.ttf
  assets:
    - assets/images/google_signin_button.png
    - assets/images/activity_feed.svg
    - assets/legal/privacy_policy.txt
    - assets/legal/terms_and_conditions.txt
    - assets/images/default_profile.png
    - assets/images/default_background.png
    - assets/images/UploadScreen.png
    - assets/images/CoolerTalkLogo.png
    - assets/images/BrightUploadScreen.png
    - assets/images/DarkUploadScreen.png
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.
  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

---

I made another quick flutter app (that successfully loaded suggestions) to test the location autocomplete with the same pubspec.yaml and same build / usage of the api.
Here is my code in my buggy coolertalk app:

```
import 'package:coolertalk/models/user.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_google_places/flutter_google_places.dart' as google;
import 'package:google_maps_webservice/places.dart' as web;
final DateTime currentTimestamp = DateTime.now();
class UploadTextNoPic extends StatefulWidget {
  final String currentUserId;
  final User currentUser;
  UploadTextNoPic({this.currentUserId, this.currentUser});
  @override
  _UploadTextNoPicState createState() => _UploadTextNoPicState();
}
class _UploadTextNoPicState extends State<UploadTextNoPic> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("WELCOME TO TESTING GOOGLE PLACES");
  }
  void onError(web.PlacesAutocompleteResponse response) {
    print(response.errorMessage);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () async {
        const kGoogleApiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY";
        web.Prediction p = await google.PlacesAutocomplete.show(
            onError: onError,
            radius: 100000,
            strictbounds: false,
            types: [],
            context: context,
            apiKey: kGoogleApiKey,
            mode: google.Mode.overlay, // Mode.fullscreen
            language: "en",
            components: [
              new web.Component(
                web.Component.country,
                "usa",
              ),
              new web.Component(web.Component.country, "fr")
            ]);
      },
      child: Text("Hello"),
    );
  }
}
```

---

And here is my pubspec.yaml for my test app:

```
name: location_help
description: A new Flutter project.
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_google_places: ^0.2.8
  google_maps_webservice: ^0.0.19
  geocoding: ^1.0.5
  geolocator: ^6.2.1
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.
  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

---

As well as the code that implements the libraries / api:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_google_places/flutter_google_places.dart' as google;
import 'package:google_maps_webservice/places.dart' as web;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Location(),
    );
  }
}



class Location extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: 250.0,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "WELCOME TO DEBUGING",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple, fontSize: 20),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Container(
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.purple)),
                child: TextField(
                  onTap: () async {
                    const kGoogleApiKey =
                        "YOUR_API_KEY";

                    web.Prediction p = await google.PlacesAutocomplete.show(
                        radius: 100000,
                        strictbounds: false,
                        types: [],
                        context: context,
                        apiKey: kGoogleApiKey,
                        mode: google.Mode.overlay, // Mode.fullscreen
                        language: "en",
                        components: [
                          new web.Component(
                            web.Component.country,
                            "usa",
                          ),
                          new web.Component(web.Component.country, "fr")
                        ]);
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```